# Converted excel sheet to json and update db column

Tags: php

I have converted the excel sheet into JSON. How can I update the column in a DB for each row:

```
$employes = 
'{"Column1.id":1,"Column1.name":"Test user","Column1.password":"password"},{"Column1.id":2,"Column1.name":"Test user 2","Column1.password":"I3D62"},{"Column1.id":3,"Column1.name":"Test user 3","Column1.password":"G2M96"},{"Column1.id":4,"Column1.name":"Test user 4","Column1.password":"I5N68"}';
```

How to create an array for each row, and then in foreach loop update the password for each id?

I was trying to set employes as an array

```
$employees = array();
$employes[] = 
'{"Column1.id":1,"Column1.name":"Test user","Column1.password":"pAasasdasword"},{"Column1.id":2,"Column1.name":"Test user 2","Column1.password":"Iasd3a62"},{"Column1.id":3,"Column1.name":"Test user 3","Column1.password":"Gs2Mass9sads6"},{"Column1.id":4,"Column1.name":"Test user 4","Column1.password":"Isad5Nasd68"}';
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use `json_decode`. https://www.php.net/json_decode

But your json string is wrong. Objects are not in an array. So if you do this to correct:

```php
$json = '{"Column1.id":1,"Column1.name":"Test user","Column1.password":"password"},{"Column1.id":2,"Column1.name":"Test user 2","Column1.password":"I3D62"},{"Column1.id":3,"Column1.name":"Test user 3","Column1.password":"G2M96"},{"Column1.id":4,"Column1.name":"Test user 4","Column1.password":"I5N68"}';

// Wrap json string in an array and decode:
$employes = json_decode('['.$json.']', true);
```

Result:

```
   [
     {
       +"Column1.id": 1,
       +"Column1.name": "Test user",
       +"Column1.password": "password",
     },
     {
       +"Column1.id": 2,
       +"Column1.name": "Test user 2",
       +"Column1.password": "I3D62",
     },
     {
       +"Column1.id": 3,
       +"Column1.name": "Test user 3",
       +"Column1.password": "G2M96",
     },
     {
       +"Column1.id": 4,
       +"Column1.name": "Test user 4",
       +"Column1.password": "I5N68",
     },
   ]
```